# How did Draco apparate within Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, draco-malfoy

In the film *The Deathly Hallows Pt. 2*, right before The Battle of Hogwarts starts, Draco Apparates to the dungeons to get Goyle and Blaise Zabini.

Since it's impossible to apparate or disapparate within the walls of Hogwarts (aside from Dumbledore, of course) **how was Draco able to do so?**

Comment: That was the movie. This doesn't happen in the books.

Comment: @Slytherincess - retagged correctly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no definitive canon answer in the film canon that I know of (including on any of the extra features on DH2 Blue-Ray, interviews, or the script).

However, in DH2 film, Death Eaters are able to Apparate around the castle during the battle (and Voldemort, when fighting Harry as well); meaning that the Anti-Apparation Jinx isn't in effect anymore.

Possible explanations are that:

1. Voldemort had managed to break the Anti-Disapparation spells when he broke the wards
2. Or they were sabotaged by Snape earlier on his orders, acting as Headmaster. As we can see from *Half-Blood Prince* [movie script](http://web.archive.org/web/20110101193134/http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Harry-Potter-and-the-Half-Blood-Prince.html), Harry and Dumbledore Apparated at the Astronomy Tower, and Dumbledore told Harry he can open/close "windows" for apparation, as Headmaster:

   > DUMBLEDORE: Take my arm.
   >   HARRY: Sir, I thought one couldn'ta apparate within Hogwarts.
   >   DUMBLEDORE: Being me has its privileges.
   >
   > EXT. ASTRONOMY TOWER - NIGHT (MOMENTS LATER)
   >   Harry and Dumbledore materialize on the rooftop ...
   >   ...
   >   Harry ...  sees Dumbledore MUTTERING WEARILY as he GESTICULATES with his blackened hand.
   >   HARRY: Sir, are you... praying?
   >   DUMBLEDORE: (smiling faintly) No, Harry. I do not pray. I was merely closing a window -- the one that had allowed us to Apparate.

Comment: Or maybe, death of Dumbledore removed that for good?

Comment: i so love that last quotes !! +1 from my part

Comment: @SachinShekhar - unlikely. But then again, these are the films, so anything's possible

Comment: He doesn't actually say that *as Headmaster* he can open and close windows for appraration. While "being me has its privileges" could mean that he can do it because he is Headmaster, my reading of it was that he can do it because *he's Dumbledore*.

Comment: "Because he's Dumbledore" can explain anything. It's the HP version of "because he's Batman".

Comment: On-screen dialog about charms against apparation seemed to imply a purpose of  protection against infiltration from outside, with no mention of apparation from point to point once inside. I had assumed (based solely on the movies) that the charms were therefore only preventing apparation into or out of Hogwarts.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a movie mistake. In the books, for example in the 6th, Harry and Dumbledore have to fly to Hogsmeade in brooms and then apparate from there because you simply can’t do it in Hogwarts. In the 7th book, there isn’t any mention of anyone apparating, in fact, the long duel and fight between Harry and Voldemort (where Voldemort apparates many times) that we see in the film, is actually a long chat in the Great Hall where Harry reveals Snape’s true loyalty, and then they have a brief duel where Voldemort’s curse rebounds and kills him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question was posed about the movie version of the universe, so answering from the book doesn't really help.  As noted in the other answer, there _is_ precedent, so the question is why was it possible for Draco at this point?

Answer (score 0):

There are anti-apparition and anti-disapparition charms in Hogwarts before the Death Eaters took over.

During the Battle of Hogwarts the school enhanced the magical enchantments that protected the school. Then later Voldemort used the Elder Wand, the most powerful wand in existence. He used that wand to destroy the magical barrier in an instant, including the anti-apparition and anti-disapparition charms.

But because Voldemort didn't earn the wand, he was forcing it to utilize it's power which was causing it to break, and if he kept it up the wand would broke into pieces. It was powerful in its own right, but as Voldy said, it was holding back its power.

Anyway, Draco only apparates AFTER Voldy uses the Elder Wand and destroys the protective enchantments.

So in short, Draco could apparate because Voldy got rid of the magical protective charms.

Comment: What evidence do you have for these claims?

Comment: That's information gained from the films themselves as well as this film. In Half-Blood Prince Harry said you couldn't apparate in and out of Hogwarts (this info can also be found in the wiki) The film (Deathly Hallows Part 2) purposely shows Draco apparating ONLY AFTER Voldemort uses the wand which breaks the magical shield which enhanced the magical protections as well as adding new ones. The evidence is from the film itself. It's inference comes from paying attention to the dialogue and scenes from past movies and this one.

Comment: Side note: I know fandom wikis are not the most reliable source, but I still believe that they are credible to a massive degree considering fans make the wiki and gather info from the books and films as well as info from J.K. Rowling's interviews and her website, as well as the Wizarding World website, which also contains some info from the author.  I didn't use any info from the wiki in this case, but I just wanted to give my stance on it

Answer (score -2):

I think because of Dumbledore's death, all the enchantments he cast over the school were gone. If anyone recalls, in The Half-Blood Prince, when Dumbledore passed away the *Petrificus Totalus* he cast on Harry was released. I believe the Anti-Apparation Jinx was also lifted when Dumbledore died.

Comment: You think?  You believe?  Could you please add some evidence for this?  That would make a much better answer.