# Are there any references of students (i.e. Hermione) using Apparition outside classes?

Tags: harry-potter, apparition

I'm aware that *Apparition* is taught to the students, but I wonder if there's any student using this spell besides, for example, **Hermione**, in *The Deadly Hallows* if I'm not mistaken, when she takes Harry and Ron with her.
Any mention you can find about this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you not answer your question with the example you gave above?

Comment: I want to know if there's any other references of this topic

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Apparition

Comment: Since the Apparition lessons weren't really normal _classes_ as such, I'd say the question is more whether there are any known instances of students using Apparition **in** classes. (The answer is presumably no, since you can't Apparate within Hogwarts except for the Hall during Apparition lessons—not until the 1997/98 year, at any rate.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concentrating only on those who're young enough to be students during the events of the Harry Potter novels;

- Both **Fred and George Weasley** use apparation within the confines of Grimmauld Place in 'Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix'

> With two loud cracks, Fred and George, Ron’s elder twin brothers, had
>   materialised out of thin air in the middle of the room. Pigwidgeon
>   twittered more wildly than ever and zoomed off to join Hedwig on top
>   of the wardrobe.

- **Harry Potter** apparates in Deathly Hallows

> Meanwhile, inside number twelve, Harry had just entered the hall. He
>   had nearly lost his balance as he Apparated on to the top step just
>   outside the front door, and thought that the Death Eaters might have
>   caught a glimpse of his momentarily exposed elbow

- As does **Ron Weasley (and Hermione, obviously)**

> She was impeded by her own Shield Charm; by the time she had removed it, he had already stormed into the night. Harry stood quite still and silent, listening to her sobbing and calling Ron’s name amongst the trees.
>   After a few minutes she returned, her sopping hair plastered to her face.
>   ‘He’s g – g – gone! Disapparated!’

- **Graham Montague** apparates after becoming stuck in the vanishing cabinet

> Montague told me that when he was stuck in the Hogwarts one, he was
>   trapped in limbo but sometimes he could hear what was going on at
>   school, and sometimes what was going on in the shop, as if the Cabinet
>   was travelling between them, but he couldn’t make anyone hear him ...
>   in the end he managed to Apparate out, even though he’d never passed
>   his test.

<sub><sup>(h/t to [Himarm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126448/are-there-any-references-of-students-i-e-hermione-using-apparition-outside-cl/126449#comment316336_126450) & [Evdzhan Mustafa](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/126450/20774))</sup></sub>

---

- In the film-verse, **Draco Malfoy** [apparates into the Hogwarts dungeon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76889/how-did-draco-apparate-within-hogwarts) in order to to rescue Goyle and Blaise Zabini in Deathly Hallows, Pt II.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Graham Montague, uses apparation to escape from the vanishing cabient which was later moved to the RoR. I believe Fred and George stuck him there to retaliate for him abusing his powers during the Umbridge regime.

Comment: The quote from the book is ***‘They’ve found Montague, sir, he’s turned up jammed inside a toilet on the fourth floor.’
‘How did he get in there?’ demanded Snape.
‘I don’t know, sir, he’s a bit confused.’.*** It doesn't say that he apparated...

Comment: @Richard "Montague told me that

when he was stuck in the Hogwarts one, he was trapped in

limbo but sometimes he could hear what was going on at

school, and sometimes what was going on in the shop, as if

the Cabinet was travelling between them, but he couldn’t

make anyone hear him ... in the end he managed to Apparate

out, even though he’d never passed his test."

Comment: @Richard which makes me wonder how he apparated into a toilet in Hogwarts.

Comment: @Himarm - Ah, OK. I missed that part. I just assumed the vanishing cabinet spat him out.

Comment: @Richard it just spat him out in book 5, but in book 6 he apparated out, because she forgot and her editors are bad i guess, and both forgot you cant apparate at hogwarts, whatever,

Comment: @Himarm - Presumably he apparated on the Borgin and Burke's side of the wormhole

Comment: @Richard but ended up in the hogwarts bathrooms

Comment: Slight inaccuracy: the Vanishing Cabinet wasn’t put in the Room of Requirement until after Montague got out of it. It was on the first floor when Fred and George shoved him into it.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the good answer from Richard:

There was also :

- Percy, after he passed his apparition test, at the Burrow

> "Percy only passed two weeks ago," said George. "He's been Apparating downstairs every morning since, just to prove he can."
> *(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 6, The Portkey)*

- *[Side-Along Apparition]* Harry (thanks to Dumbledore) when they went to Slughorn's

> Harry gripped Dumbledore's proffered forearm.
>
> "Very good," said Dumbledore. "Well, here we go."
>
> Harry felt Dumbledore's arm twist away from him and redoubled his grip; the next thing he knew, everything went black; he was being pressed very hard from all directions; he could not breathe, there were iron bands tightening around his chest; his eyeballs were being forced back into his head; his eardrums were being pushed deeper into his skull and then--
>
> He gulped great lungfulls of cold night air and opened his streaming eyes. He felt as though he had just been forced through a very tight rubber tube. It was a few seconds before he realized that Privet Drive had vanished. He and Dumbledore were now standing in what appeared to be a deserted village square, in the center of which stood an old war memorial and a few benches. His comprehension catching up with his senses, Harry realized that he had just Apparated for the first time in his life.
> *(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4, Horace Slughorn)*

- *[Side-Along Apparition]* Harry (thanks to Dumbledore) when they went from Slughorn's to the Burrow

> "This will do, Harry. If you will grasp my arm."
>
> Braced this time, Harry was ready for the Apparition, but still found it unpleasant. When the pressure disappeared and he found himself able to breathe again, he was standing in a country lane beside Dumbledore and looking ahead to the crooked silhouette of his second favorite building in the world: the Burrow.
> *(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 4, Horace Slughorn)*

- *[Side-Along Apparition - or something like "Helped Apparition"]* Harry (thanks to Dumbledore) when they went to the cave

> "It will not be necessary for us to enter," muttered Dumbledore, glancing around. "As long as nobody sees us go ... now place your hand upon my arm, Harry. There is no need to grip too hard, I am merely guiding you. On the count of three--one ... two ... three ..."
>
> Harry turned. At once, there was that horrible sensation that he was being squeezed through a thick rubber tube; he could not draw breath, every part of him was being compressed almost past endurance and then, just when he thought he must suffocate, the invisible bands seemed to burst open, and he was standing in cool darkness, breathing in lungfuls of fresh, salty air.
> *(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 25, The Seer Overheard)*

- *[Side-Along Apparition with a student as "leader"]* Harry ("carrying" Dumbledore) when they got back from the cave

> Sodden and shivering, Dumbledore's weight still upon him, Harry concentrated harder than he had ever done upon his destination: Hogsmeade. Closing his eyes, gripping Dumbledore's arm as tightly as he could, he stepped forwards into that feeling of horrible compression.
>
> He knew it had worked before he opened his eyes: the smell of salt, the sea breeze had gone. He and Dumbledore were shivering and dripping in the middle of the dark High Street in Hogsmeade.
> *(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 27, The Lightning-Struck Tower)*

- *[Side-Along Apparition? thanks to Snape? Another Death Eater? or maybe Regular Apparition]* Draco when he fled with Snape and the DeathEaters - I can't find a quote telling it, it happened between:

> Snape and Malfoy, however, were still running; they would soon be beyond the gates, able to Disapparate--
> *(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 28, Flight of the Prince)*

and

> Snape had managed to Disapparate just beyond the school's boundaries.
> *(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 28, Flight of the Prince)*

Not to mention of course the Apparition lessons, Apparition Test in Hogsmeade and the many Apparitions of Harry, Ron and Hermione in the *Deathly Hallows* (some of them being Side-Along Apparitions led by one of them, some others being Regular Apparitions). And also from Dean and Luna, helped by Dobby.

Comment: I didn't count side-along apparition which is what we seem to see from Dumbledore/Harry (the first couple of times) and Snape/Draco (probably).

Comment: @Richard I wasn't sure whether these cases were wished, but since it's Apparition... I'll mark these cases as so for a better clarity;
(For Snape and Draco I'm not so sure... there's a bit of time between these two quotes : Harry runs after them, tries and fights with Snape... I always thought Draco hadn't wait for Snape and had disappeared in the meantime. But no proof. And maybe another DE side-along apparated with him...)